# Android application refresh position on Google street view

Tags: android, google-maps

I m building an Android application. In this application I m using Google Street View, I start from a point (longitude and latitude), after that I receive data from a sensor that tells me how many meters I have to advance my vision, but through the Google API I can go forward with my screen but not the meters I want. How could I solve?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Get the location of the new Panorama View when it changes using the `OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener`

The `StreetViewPanorama` in the Maps SDK for Android has a **Public Method** called:

```
public abstract void onStreetViewPanoramaChange (StreetViewPanoramaLocation location)
```

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanorama.OnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener#public-abstract-void-onstreetviewpanoramachange-streetviewpanoramalocation-location):

> The **StreetViewPanorama** performs an animated transition from one
> location to another when the user performs a manual navigation action.
> This callback is called when the transition animation has occurred and
> the rendering of the first panorama has occurred. This callback also
> occurs when the developer sets a position and the rendering of the
> first panorama has occurred. It is possible that not all the panoramas
> have loaded when this callback is activated. Implementations of this
> method are always invoked on the main thread.

This method has a parameter `location` that has a property `position` by accessing it through `location.position` that returns a `latLng` value of the new location whenever this method is called when the Panorama View changes.

I'm assuming that your sensors return a `latLng` value. If so, you can utilize the [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility) and use the spherical geometry utility's method `computeDistanceBetween()` which `Returns the distance, in meters, between two latitude/longitude coordinates.`

You can invoke the `computeDistanceBetween()` everytime the `onStreetViewPanoramaChange()` is called. You can do it like this:

### Java

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation location) {
    if (location != null) {
        // use the location parameter as your first location argument
        // then use your sensor location as your second location argument
        // Then put your method - computeDistanceBetween(LatLng location, LatLng sensorLocation)
    }
}
```

### Kotlin

```
override fun onStreetViewPanoramaChange(location: StreetViewPanoramaLocation) {
    // use the location parameter as your first location argument
    // then use your sensor location as your second location argument
    // Then put your method - computeDistanceBetween(location: LatLng, sensorLocation: LatLng)
}
```

See this [reference documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) for more information.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for asking, my sensor return me the speed and how many meters I traveled.

Comment: What have you tried so far?